# How do I get a specific error message for a thrown exception in Java?

Tags: validation, exception, try-catch, message, throw

I'm trying to get two different messages for errors.  One to display: "X-Coordinate out of bounds", and the other "Please enter a number".  This is how I thought you'd write the code but, ofcourse, doesn't work.

```
int x = -1;
int y = 0;

while(x < 0 || y < 0)
{
   try
   {
      System.out.println("X-Coordinate: ");
      x = kb.nextInt();
      if (x < 0)
      {
         throw new Exception("X-Coordinate out of bounds"); // desired message
      }
      System.out.println("Y-Coordinate: ");
      y = kb.nextInt();
      if (y < 0)
      {
         throw new Exception("Y-Coordinate out of bounds"); // desired message
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      // Desired default for other input errors
      System.out.println("Please enter a number"); 
      kb.nextLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the message in the catch block like so using the `getMessage()` method:

```
try{
    throw new Exception("LOL I HAVE ERROR");
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("My error message: " + e.getMessage());
}
```